# Get the position of Item base on the value of TAG of custom view adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let's say I have `RecyclerView` which contain a custom view adapter. Each item has a hidden view and its view has a `TAG` with a different value. For example one of the hidden view, its `TAG` contains a value of `hidden01`.

**QUESTION:** how do you know which of the `View` has the value of `hidden01`? And how do you know which position of that item? or How do you know the position of that item base on the `TAG` of the `hidden view`?

**UPDATE:** I only have the below code for my Adapter, This is also where I want to get the position of that item, Please see the last function `getPositionBaseOnTag`.

```
 public class TheRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheRecyclerAdapter.TheViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<TheData> theDataList;

    public class TheViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView theHiddenView;

        public TheViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            theHiddenView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hiddenView);
        }
    }

    public TheRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<TheData> theDatalist){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.theDataList = theDatalist;
    }

    @Override
    public TheViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_view_adapter, parent, false);
        return new TheViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TheViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TheData theData = theDataList.get(position);
        holder.theHiddenView.setTag(theData.getHiddenTag()); //Set the TAG of Hidden View here
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return theDataList.size();
    }

    public void deletePosition(int position){
        theDataList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position,theDataList.size());
    }

    public void removeTheItem(){
         deletePosition(getPositionBaseOnTag("my_tag"));
    }

    /***Here where I want to return the position of that Item base on TAG**/
    public int getPositionBaseOnTag(String theTag){
        int itemPosition;

        //Find the View base on TAG
        //Get the Position
        //Done

        return itemPosition;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you code something ? If yes please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>There are two ways to do this:</s>

**1)** Loop over theDataList in your getPositionBaseOnTag(String theTag) method and if the theTag matches getHiddenTag() then return that index:

```
public int getPositionBaseOnTag(String theTag) {
  int length = theDataList.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
    if(theDataList.get(i).getHiddenTag().equals(theTag)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  // unable to find the tag
  return -1;
}
```

We concluded in the comment chain that this approach is not valid for Seynal's needs.

<s>**2)** Make a pojo to hold the tag and the position and store that as the view tag:</s>

Add this inner class to TheRecyclerAdapter:

```
private class TagPojo {
  int position;
  String tag;

  public TagPojo(int position, String tag) {
    this.position = position;
    this.tag = tag;
  }
}
```

Then in your onBindViewHolder do this:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TheViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TheData theData = theDataList.get(position);
        holder.theHiddenView.setTag(new TagPojo(position, theData.getHiddenTag())); //Set the TAG of Hidden View here
    }
```

And you getPositionBaseOnTag() should look like this:

```
public int getPositionBaseOnTag(TagPojo theTag) {
  return theTag.position;
}
```

**Also,** I am not sure how your code is compiling, but I think that your onBindViewHolder method needs to be corrected:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TheViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TheData theData = theDataList.get(position);
        holder.theHiddenView.setTag(theData.getHiddenTag()); //Set the TAG of Hidden View here
    }
```

Last nitpick, make sure that you are calling your getPositionBaseOnTag() somewhere. Right now it looks unused.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Nitpick, I'll try one of your way. I'll update you if it works. Thanks! I'm sorry for `onBindViewHolder`, that was actually `holder.theHiddenView.setTag(theData.getHiddenTag());`, It was a comment I just delete the line and uncomment that wrong line. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which one is the best way anyway? the one `Loop over theDataList` or the `pojo to hold the tag`?

Comment: The pojo approach is going to be more efficient if theDataList is large. The other approach is more efficient if theDataList is short. Try em both out and pick the one that seems more elegant to you. I personally favor the pojo approach.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I am actually thinking about pojo approach since my datalist will become large later. I'll try it now.

Comment: I already try `Loop over theDataList` and it's work fine. However in the second approach, I'm having problem in `getPositionBaseOnTag(TagPojo theTag)`. 
I am calling it like `int x = getPositionBaseOnTag("my_tag");` but the parameter is incorrect. What should be the parameter?

Comment: Okay, now that I think of it my suggestion to use a pojo may not be applicable. I made an assumption that you are using your getPositionBaseOnTag() method a specific way. Could you share how you are using it?

Comment: It's OK it was my mistake too, Sorry, I didn't tell it clearly. Anyway there's nothing more special on it. I just want to call that method to `return` the `position` of an Item base on the `TAG` so I can tell which position do I have to remove from the list of RecyclerView. Thanks @Dr. Nitpick. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: No problem mate. Okay, I was thinking that you wanted to call getPositionBaseOnTag() from a click listener placed on the list item (so when you click on it, the item would get deleted). In that case the Pojo approach would work since you could get the pojo off the tag of the view being tapped on. Clearly I was way off with that so the loop approach is appropriate here. Ill amend my answer